# How to insert icon in site title

Tags: title, icon

I'm trying to insert an icon using the font awesome icon plugin, via the

Customisations > Appearance > Site Title

But this just displays the code, not the icon.

Anyone know the solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That setting is html escaped, it means that all the html special chars are converted in the realated html entities, so e.g. `<` became `&lt;`.

To print correctly you can use `echo html_entity_decode( get_option('blogname') );`

However be aware, that `blogname` option is used by Wordpress and by a lot WP themes and plugins (e.g. SEO plugins) that aspect that options containt text without any html. For this reason, maybe, is not a good idea insert html code in that option.